# `Array#join` on nested arrays only

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of arrays. The second element of each subarray is further an array:

```
arr = [
  ["val1", ["The cat", "3"]],
  ["val2", ["Big", "Another", "6"]],
  ["val3", ["343"]]
]
```

I would like to convert the array so that the arrays at the third nested level are each joined into one string separated by a space and comma like this:

```
[["val1", "The cat, 3"], ["val2", "Big, Another, 6"], ["val3", "343"]]
```

How do I call `join` on just the nested arrays?

Comment: When you give an example, please assign variables to all input objects. For example, `arr = [[["val1",..]]]`. That way readers can refer to `arr` in comments and answers without having to define it.

Comment: I have seen your questions here a few times now. Just a tip, maybe you should not use array of arrays. Maybe a Hash would be a better data structure for you data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr.map{|e, a| [e, a.join(", ")]}
# => [["val1", "The cat, 3"], ["val2", "Big, Another, 6"], ["val3", "343"]]
```

Comment: Well @sawa its defiantly time I look into `map` you keep answering my questions with it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Do the following to your `array`

```
array.map {|el| el.flatten}
```

**Edit** : Per your update, you can accomplish joining the deeply nested arrays as follows:

```
array.map {|x| x.map {|y| y.is_a?(Array) ? y.join(', ') : y}}
```

Answer (score 1):

map and flatten are your friends!

```
a.map(&:flatten)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by concatenating it inside a loop.

```
arr = [["val1", ["The cat", "3"]], ["val2", ["Big", "Another", "6"]], ["val3", ["343"]]

arr.map{|a| [a.first] + a.last}
#=> [["val1", "The cat", "3"], ["val2", "Big", "Another", "6"], ["val3", "343"]]
```

Or simply `flatten` in inner arrays:

```
arr.map(&:flatten)
```

Comment: Problem with flatten is that I need to have the array values in one string seperated by a comma. Thats why I went with `.join`